# Can I install two Ubuntu versions on the same machine?

Tags: 10.10, installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have Ubuntu 10.10 32 bit already installed on my machine..I am using MongoDB and it does not work properly with 32 bit machine.

So I want to install 64 bit Ubuntu 10.10 on my system on another partition (so that I can have both 32 bit and 64 bit versions).

Is it okay to install both 32 bit and 64 bit? I mean will it give any problems?
On which partition should I install the 64 bit version? My partitions are as follows:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              37G   11G   25G  30% /
none                  1.4G  260K  1.4G   1% /dev
none                  1.4G  776K  1.4G   1% /dev/shm
none                  1.4G  244K  1.4G   1% /var/run
none                  1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /var/lock
/dev/sda6             129G   73G   50G  60% /home
/dev/sda7             127G   76G   45G  64% /vol
```

Waiting for your replies.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can.
For that you will have to use manual partition option.

1. You can use the same swap for both the installs (this is simple, just select re-select same swap for second install).
2. You can mount same /home for both installs. (a little advanced, if your experience with linux-admin is less.)

Comment: How swap will react if both system will use hibernation? And same /home will make both have same installations.. Better additional same files.. some settings synced and some file folder synced but not whole /home. i can try to find later in askubuntu where i found someone had problem with same /home with different ubuntu versions and programm versions merging.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to consider a virtual machine to save time. With a virtual machine you wouldn't require a reboot of your computer. Virtualbox is easy to install and free. You can either get it from the software center in Ubuntu or you can download the non open source edition at... http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Here's a walk through of how to install Ubuntu inside virtualbox.

http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/how-to-install-ubuntu-in-virtualbox/

The walk through is for Ubuntu 9.04, but the steps are the same. Easy to do and you don't need to reboot to switch to the 64 bit version or partition your drive any more than how it is.