# Can I have two Ubuntu installations on one laptop?

Tags: installation, partitioning

Can I have 2 Ubuntus 12.10 on my laptop? 
I need 1 for work, and 1 as desktop. Will it work if I install new version as usual, beside existing one? 
I can't lose data from my actual Ubuntu, but want to have new one too.

I have many services running (mysql, rabbitmq, apache, memcached etc.) and I don't want to run them all the time. That's why I want second OS to use it as normal desktop.

Comment: No. I need to be sure before trying.

Comment: Like Fernhill Linux Project and Alvar have mentioned, I would seriously consider using two user accounts instead of two partitions.

Comment: @duxk.gh can I disable services (apache, mysql, memcached etc.) for new account?

Comment: Someone who knows for sure will have to verify, but I think so. What I do know is that you can have completely different software on the two and use entirely different settings, so I expect you'll be able to disable those services as well (as long as they're not required to run Ubuntu or start before logging in). But I am not very knowledgeable in this area; take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40072/how-to-stop-apache2-mysql-from-starting-automatically-as-computer-starts) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/whats-the-recommended-way-to-enable-disable-services).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that will work fine.

Use the "Something Else" option on the installer to manually select the partition to install to.

You could also use separate user accounts for work & personal & public use

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure you can. Just install the second one like you would the first one, but use a different partition. If you need help installing: [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

This can help as well: [Can I install two Ubuntu versions on the same machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28398/can-i-install-two-ubuntu-versions-on-the-same-machine)